# #include directive: difference between "test.h" and "./test.h"

Tags: include, c-preprocessor

Is there any difference between `#include "./test.h"` and `#include "test.h"` for the C/C++ preprocessor?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no difference.

You could also have

```
#include "../thisdir/test.h"
```

And it would be the same

Comment: You would have to change all your #includes if you renamed the directory though

Comment: And if I did "../../thisdir/test.h", it would be a nightmare :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the C standard, there is no difference: the compiler gets to specify how they are searched. In practice, there shouldn't be any difference, either, for any of the implementations I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Both styles will be treated the same by the pre-processor. The standard practice is

```
#include "test.h"
```

and pass the include file path as an option to the compiler. (For instance, the -I option of GCC). This makes it easy to change the location of header files. You just need to make a single change in the project's make file.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion there is an important difference.

In the case of `#include "test.h"` the include file is searched for in all directories specified to the compiler with the option -I.

In the case of `#include "./test.h"` only the residing directory of the referring file is used.

Comment: Isnt the -I option used for adding "standard " directories to the include path ( that is, a directory that will be scanned on an angled bracket include )

Comment: @Tom, assuming we are talking about gcc, -I specifies directories to search for both "" and <> includes.  You can use -isystem to specify paths that should only be searched for angle brackets.

Comment: Not true. Both will still search through all directories. Just that "" will search the local directories before looking at those specified with -I